# Close modal before Response.Flush - C#

Tags: javascript, c#, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with modal closing ...
So I have this button `btnReportingExport` that's inside of modal

```
<div id="Reporting_footer" class="modal-footer">
    <asp:Button ID="btnReportingExport" runat="server" Text="Export" 
                CssClass="btn btn-default" OnClientClick="ChangeModalFunction();" 
                OnClick="btnReportingExport_Click"/>
    <input id="Submit1" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" 
           value="Cancel" />
</div>
```

That button first calls JS function `ChangeModalFunction` that looks like this

```
function ChangeModalFunction() {
       $('#Reporting_modal').modal('hide');
       $('#GenerateReport_modal').modal('toggle');
}
```

So i just hide modal and show another modal that only has some `.gif` animation on it for generating the report. After that my main event happens `btnReportingExport_Click` that does loads of stuff, taking data from SQL, putting it on excel, converting to PDF, zipping and putting it into response
It looks like this ...

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/x-zip-compressed";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
  string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}.zip\"", QuestionnaireName));

Response.WriteFile(FilePathZip);
```

So what I wish to accomplish, but failing miserably is to close the modal with a `.gif` on it, right before I flush my response ... and I got no clue how to do it anymore

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
                                    "CloseModal", "Closepopup();", true);

Response.Flush();
```

`Closepopup` function is just simple function that does

```
function Closepopup() {
    $('#GenerateReport_modal').modal('hide');
}
```

So after that long code trip, my problem shows up, I get download file dialog and my modal is still up and running in background. And I am all out of ideas how to fix it, how can I hide modal from code before doing the `Response.Flush()`?

Thank you for help and I apologize for wall of text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting scenario, I would like you to try the following solution:
call your zip file endpoint via ajax request using jquery (you can do it also with vanilla javascript). And then bind this event `onreadystatechange` to your request.

```
$(".submitButton").click(function(){
    var xhr  = $.ajax({url: "/data.zip",
     success: function(result){

    }});
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if(xhr.readyState === 4)
            Closepopup();
    };
});
```

this event will fire with 5 different statuses:

1. 0: request not initialized
2. 1: server connection established
3. 2: request received
4. 3: processing request
5. 4: request finished and response is ready

I believe that when you will get this status 4, the dialog will open in the same time and you could close your popup window.

Comment: Thank you so much, I understand this is the right way to do it ... but my AJAX knowledge is bad to accomplish it this way ... with a little bit of help from @JABFreeware I figured out a way to create a cookie that will be checked once creation of report has been started, after cookie value has been changed I close the modal and destroy the cookie and stop interval of checking